# Can't validate Flutter iOS application to AppStore

Tags: ios, flutter

I've prepared my app to AppStore, successfully built it in Xcode and then try to Validate and got an error:
"App Store Connect Operation Error
No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'io.flutter.flutter' is correct."

I use another identifier in the app. It is the 2 build of version, first was successfully uploaded to TestFlight two weeks ago. What's wrong?

Comment: I've solved the problem. It's necessary to replace the value for CFBundleExecutable from $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME) to $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) in the file ios/Runner/Info.plist

Comment: I suggest adding that as an answer and marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle identifier has been set wrongly (`io.flutter.flutter`). It needs to match the bundle identifier from the developer portal and the app created on App Store Connect. Change it to the one you use in the app.

Comment: Thank you Adis, but I've wrote that the app has another bundle identifier. It looks like  Flutter use io.flutter.flutter in some dependencies which are embedded in the app by non suitable way.

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to replace the value for CFBundleExecutable from $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME) to $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) in the file ios/Runner/Info.plist